LSI 9266-8i Replaced - have I destroyed my old configuration?
I had a recent crash of my LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266-8i card on which I had a 5.7TB RAID 5 configuration involving 4 2TB drives.  This was running on a UBUNTU 22.04 system that I built years ago.
I ordered and received a replacement 9266-8i (supposed to be new but there was no doc, no box, no anti-static bag, etc.  But I digress).  This card had a preexisting configuration on it (!!!!!), and lacking documentation I have had fits trying to get this to work on Ubuntu.
Thankfully, I found lots of sites that helped me out, a piece here, a piece there, and I finally was able to get it configured, to a point.  (I still haven't found what it takes to run Megaraid Storage Manager on Ubuntu, though I did get it installed.  I suspect that tool would be ultra-useful in such a situation.  But alas!)
The final answer that helped me out was Megacli is killing me, any help appreciated - specifically the answer with only 1 vote, answered by Alex answered Oct 25, 2016 at 6:45.
Here's a little history of the last few steps: (some formatting, for clarity)
root@r2d2alt:~# megacli -CfgLdAdd -r5 [252:4,252:5,252:6,252:7] -a0
    The specified physical disk does not have the appropriate attributes to complete the requested command.
    Exit Code: 0x26

root@r2d2alt:~# megacli -CfgForeign -Scan -aall
    There are 4 foreign configuration(s) on controller 0.
    Exit Code: 0x00

root@r2d2alt:~# megacli -CfgForeign -Clear -aall
    Foreign configuration 0 is cleared on controller 0.
    Foreign configuration 1 is cleared on controller 0.
    Foreign configuration 2 is cleared on controller 0.
    Foreign configuration 3 is cleared on controller 0.
    Exit Code: 0x00

root@r2d2alt:~# megacli -CfgLdAdd -r5 [252:4,252:5,252:6,252:7] -a0
    Adapter 0: Created VD 0
    Adapter 0: Configured the Adapter!!
    Exit Code: 0x00

So now I have a "happy" 9266-8i card, but when I boot the system I have a 5.7TB /dev/sda with no partition on it.
I fear I have misstepped, perhaps with no way back.  I am fairly certain that if I create a new partition / FS (or if I do so incorrectly) then the data will be overwritten, but I still have a glimmer of hope that at this point it's still recoverable.
As luck would have it, the same electrical storm that took out my LSI adaptor, took out the backup drive while doing the backup.  Ugh.  There is no grandfather backup per se.
If it's lost, life goes on, but I still hope there is help.
EDIT
The filesystem that was configured on that drive, is/was ext4. Hope that helps.

Yes, you destroyed pretty much all the information you could that would permit "easy fix". Instead of clearing, you had to import that foreign configuration. For now, for best, disconnect drives and don't turn then on unless you are very sure you know what you're doing. Then go search on ServerFault, there are several good answers how to proceed on your own (start by making full dumps of all drives), but even better, find a data recovery service, pay them and pray your second CfgLdAdd run had not started an initialization pass which would cleared the data area.

Also don't look for exactly "megaraid" answers; probably, you'll find out "mdadm" recipe more suitable for you, also "mdadm" supports the on-disk format megarad uses (which is called SNIA DDF). I'm afraid you had to be a RAID expert to proceed on your own on this stage. While I sympathize you, this question is off topic here.
